# Displaying Custom Fields on Post with Genesis Child Theme

Tags: custom-field, child-theme, advanced-custom-fields, genesis-theme-framework

I have tried everything to get Custom Fields to display on my posts using a Child Theme of the Genesis theme framework. I have tried to follow every tutorial I could find relating to it but still I can't get my Custom Fields to show on my posts!

The simplest looking solution I have been trying is using Brad Daltons instructions (I have tried many other methods) and adding the following to my functions file:

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_post_title', 'custom_field_before_content' );
/**
* @author Brad Dalton - WP Sites
* @link http://wp.me/p1lTu0-9WF
*/
function custom_field_before_content() {
if(is_page() || is_single() ) {
genesis_custom_field('instrument');
}
}
```

I have then added the custom field in my posts. I have tried adding the custom field with Advanced Custom Fields which shows perfectly in the admin but not on the post on my site.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong to get this to output or a different method that might work for me. I done this no problem with different themes but using the Genesis theme framework I can't get this to work - have been at it for two days!

Thanks,

Ciarán

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about instead of `genesis_custom_field('instrument');` use: `echo genesis_get_custom_field('instrument');`

Plus the `genesis_after_post_title` action hook is deprecated since 1.7.0 and you should use `genesis_entry_header` with correct priorities. For more information please use the reference links below.

Reference:

- [genesis_after_post_title](http://docs.garyjones.co.uk/genesis/2.0.0/function-genesis_after_post_title.html)
- [Genesis 2.0 Hooks reference](http://www.carriedils.com/genesis-2-0-hooks/)

Comment: That didn't seem to fix but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Ciarán Updated the answer. Seems like the hooks are deprecated. Check the new ones.

Comment: Indeed they are I should have spotted that myself! Thank you so much this was really getting the better of me! Cheers

Comment: This is working a charm. I can't seem to figure out how to style them though Do you know how I would go about styling these?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for a Custom Post Type:

Add this to functions.php. (Or, if you created a template for your custom post type like I did, such as single-instrument.php, add it to that instead of functions.php)

```
// Display Advanced Custom Fields
add_action('genesis_entry_header', 'type_of_instrument');

function type_of_attorney() {
if ( is_singular('profile') && genesis_get_custom_field('type_of_instrument') )
echo '<hr /><div id="type_of_instrument">Title: '. genesis_get_custom_field('type_of_instrument') .'</div>';
}
```

This is assuming that you named your field 'type_of_instrument' in Advanced Custom Fields. Use whatever name you actually gave the field. You'll have to adjust the code for multiple fields. It also creates a div around the field for easier styling.

If you are not using a Custom Post Type, you would want to replace `is_singular('profile')`. My guess is with `is_single` but don't quote me. If not try `if(is_page() || is_single() )` as used in the code you submitted in your question.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Good question Ciarán. I, too, was stuck trying to display custom fields in Genesis. This thread got me unstuck. And along the way I discovered that it is possible to take these ideas even farther.

For example, I have found it helpful to use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create landing pages in WordPress. I can add as many WYSIWYG fields as I need in the page and edit them all separately.

To display the fields in Genesis, I use a variation of the code given previously by Borek and user55013. In the code below, I have added div tags so that I can format each field separately with CSS:

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'display_custom_fields' );
function display_custom_fields() {
    if( is_page_template( 'page_landing.php') ) {
        printf( '<div class="landing-part-one">%s</div>', get_field('landing_part_one') );
        printf( '<div class="landing-part-two">%s</div>', get_field('landing_part_two') );
        printf( '<div class="landing-part-three">%s</div>', get_field('landing_part_three') );
        printf( '<div class="landing-part-four">%s</div>', get_field('landing_part_four') );
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, back in the options panel of the field group editor of Advanced Custom Fields, I have positioned the custom WYSIWYG fields "High (after title)" and I have hidden the content editor. This produces a clean editing space for the custom fields, which appear in the page editor as though they were native to WordPress. And in the location rules, I have set the field group to display only for the landing page template.

And though I originally tried 'genesis_get_custom_fields()' to display the fields in this function, it stripped all the `<p>` tags from the field. The output was a run-on paragraph. The Advanced Custom Fields function [get_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) works better.

Along the way I also learned the difference between 'genesis_custom_fields()' and 'genesis_get_custom_fields()'. The first echoes the field directly. The second returns the contents of the field as a string.

If you're using Advanced Custom Fields to output images, [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101928/using-custom-function-with-advanced-custom-fields) might be of use.

I hope it helps :-)